# Symfony check country for ip

Tags: php, symfony, curl, ip

Hello I use this curl for site http://ip-whois.net but if I debug in my local comp I harcode $ip = "176.241.128.140"; - this my ip that I was given by my provider and I have $out = false, why ??? 
echo curl_error ($curl); = "Empty reply from server".  I try this site http://www.ip-whois.net/ in browser and not work, what are the analogy this site who work with curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://ip-whois.net/ip_geo.php?ip='.$ip);  ?
how to do this right ?:

```
             $ip = $request->getClientIp();//I hard code $ip = "176.241.128.140"
             $record = $hAid->getInfoIpCity($ip);

            if ( $curl = curl_init() ) {
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://ip-whois.net/ip_geo.php?ip='.$ip);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
                $out = curl_exec($curl);
                $matches = array();
                $country = preg_match_all("/Страна: (.*)/i", $out, $matches);
                print_r($matches[1][1]);
                curl_close($curl);
            }
```

Comment: before print_r() do `echo curl_error ($curl);` and check message

Comment: echo curl_error ($curl); = "Empty reply from server".  I try this site http://www.ip-whois.net/ in browser and not work, what are the analogy this site who work with curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://ip-whois.net/ip_geo.php?ip='.$ip);  ?

Comment: I think its not your fault the site you try to connect is not working http://ip-whois.net/ip_geo.php?ip=176.241.128.140

Comment: ok, maybe who now analogy this site who work with curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'ip-whois.net/ip_geo.php?ip='.$ip); ?

Comment: maybe this site requires proper headers to be set and cookies to work. So you can try setting a browser and accepting cookies